# Get Influxdb V2 token only in CLI after upgrading from version 1x to 2x

Tags: grafana, upgrade, influxdb, flux, influxdb-2

Upgraded influxDb from v1.8.10 to v2.3.0+SNAPSHOT.090f681737 with below command

(https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.3/upgrade/v1-to-v2/automatic-upgrade/)

```
influxd upgrade --username='admin' --password='adminpass1234' --org='test' --bucket='testbucket' --force
```

Now trying to get or create token of influxdb with CLI commands to process with other command(like creating buckets, users and etc). To create new token I need to pass token which is only available in Influx Dashboard right now, I would like to pass username and password but only token is option (https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.3/security/tokens/create-token/)

```
influx v1 auth create -username admin
```

I don't want to go to influxdb dashboard page and get token from there because my script should work automatically without depending any manual actions in UI. It's ansible script.

Don't know if there is a any option which can help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Client config should be created during upgrade, you can list it, the output contains the token

```bash
influx config ls --json
```